Can Incremental Refresh Work Without Query Folding?
I am currently working on implementing incremental refresh in Power BI; however, I do not have the option to use query folding with my data source. Given this limitation, I would like to confirm whether it is still possible to utilize the incremental refresh feature effectively in this scenario.
Additionally, could you please outline the potential disadvantages of using incremental refresh without query folding or native queries? how much time it will take like Report+incremental refresh time =Report-without incremental refresh ? or less time please tell any any use full by using the incremental refresh
Thank you for your time and assistance.

Query folding is not an absolute requirement for incremental refresh. It is certainly preferred but incremental refresh will also work with data sources that do not support folding.
Based on the the documentation, it is not recommended to use non-foldable queries.
Without query folding, Power BI will pull the entire dataset into its memory before applying any filters or transformations.
Logically this is against how the incremental refresh works which is supposed to reduce the volume of data processed and  it could take nearly as long as a full refresh.
